# Declare multiple nested classes outside of the main class

Tags: c++, class, header

I have multiple nested classes that I want to declare outside of the main class in a separate header file, because the nested classes are very long.

This is what I want to do:

```
class MainClass {
private:
        classA;
        classB;
        classC;
        //and so on
public:
        method(C.var) {//code}
```

The problem is that I keep getting `Error:incomplete type not allowed.`because the classes have not been "defined". Is there anything I can do besides putting all the code in the `MainClass`?

Real code:

```
class Graph //fix subclass issues
{
private:
    template <class TYPE> class * linkedList;
    template <class TYPE> class * chainingTable;
    class * minHeap;    
    class * vertex;
    class * edge;

    chainingTable<vertex*> vertexList;

    vertex * findVertex(int addrs) { return vertexList.findVertex(addrs); }
    int weight(vertex *v, vertex *u) { return v->weight + u->weight; }
    void relax(vertex * v, vertex * u,int i, minHeap h)
    {
        if(v->weight > u->weight+weight(v,u))
        {
            v->weight = v->weight + weight(v,u); 
            h.decreaseKey(i, v->weight);    //fixes heap
            v->predecessor = u;
        }
    }
public:
    void addVertex(int cost, int address) 
    { vertexList.insert(new vertex(cost, address)); } //and the class continues
```

Now with these changes I am getting a `Error:  expected either a definition or tag name`

EDIT: Added real code that was requested, and added updated errors

Comment: Use pointers or references? And don't put code using those undefined classes inside the header file.

Comment: I thought using references will mean that one has to define them all in the constructor.

Comment: Do you include header of your extra classes ?

Comment: Can you post some real code for what you tried? `classA;` and `method(C.var)` are not valid C++.

Comment: @TartanLlama I added real code like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use pointers to these classes instead.

```
classA *objectA;
classB *objectB;
classC *objectC;
```

And define your methods only in the .cpp file.

To understand what is going on, when you define a class, the compiler has to know how big an object of that class will be. If you define members that has not been fully defined yet, then the compiler has no information on the size of those classes, and so it won't be able to calculate the size of objects of this class.

Pointers, however, are always the same in size (4 bytes on 32-bit and 8 on 64-bit) and the size of objects of that class could then be calculated.

ps: Note that you shouldn't define methods in .h files (header files). Header files are only supposed to have declarations of classes and .cpp files have their implementations.

e.g:
Header:

```
//--Class.h--
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H //include guards to make sure it only gets declared once
#define MY_CLASS_H

class MyClass
{
    int _member;
public:
    MyClass(); //ctor
    ~MyClass(); //dtor
    int someMethod(int a, int b);
};

#endif
```

Constructor with implementations

```
//--MyClass.cpp--
#include "MyClass.h" //include your declarations

MyClass::MyClass()
{
   //constructor
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
   //destructor
}

int MyClass::someMethod(int a, int b)
{
   //code
}
```